# If deploying apps on a world-wide basis, what about China, Japan, Korea etc.?

Tags: iphone, ipad, internationalization, app-store

I am thinking of creating an application that i would like to sell on a world-wide basis that would include the normal languages, including Chinese, Japanese, Korean etc. and would like to submit so also these countries would understand what it is.

- Given this what would be the best way of doing this?
- Is it possible to use different languages in App-store for different markets or is it only one language?

Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add in different descriptions for different languages on the app store.

And there are a few related questions here on StackOverflow that you can refer to, like:

[iPhone app available languages in appStore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896269/iphone-app-available-languages-in-appstore)

[How to add ANY language in app description on AppStore? Tremendous impact on downloads!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586632/how-to-add-any-language-in-app-description-on-appstore-tremendous-impact-on-dow)

[Submitting app - Add Localizations, but my language is not listed in the combo box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6595583/submitting-app-add-localizations-but-my-language-is-not-listed-in-the-combo-b)

[Similar languages when submitting to Apple's AppStore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6904047/similar-languages-when-submitting-to-apples-appstore)

[iTunes App Store Language String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735965/itunes-app-store-language-string)